# Creating Azure role assignments over a map of object_ids and roles

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to create a Terraform deployment that will enact azurerm_role_assignment by iterating over a list of principal_object_ids and their allocated roles. My code is roughly:

Define principal_ids and the role to allocate:

```
locals {
   subscription_access_list_by_id = {
      "SPID########1" : "reader" ,
      "SPID########1" : "storage blob data reader",
      "SPID########2" : "owner",
      "SPID########2" : "storage blob data owner"
   }
}
```

A module to allocate roles:

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "role" {
  scope                = var.subscription_id
  role_definition_name = var.role_definition_name
  principal_id         = var.object_id
}
```

A main.tf including the following block:

```
module "access-control" {
  for_each             = local.subscription_access_list
  source               = "modules/access-control"
  principal_id.        = each.key
  subscription_id      = var.subscription_id
  role_definition_name = each.value
}
```

What I actually end up seeing is that the last entry for a given service principal is the only one acted on. Ie, from the above example, SPID#######1 would get "storage blob data reader", but not "reader" and SPID######2 would get "storage blob date owner", but not "owner".

I'm assuming there is something going on where it only creates one block for each key, so the latest value overwrites it, but I'm not sure how to get round this without making a more complicated implementation of my subscription_access_list_by_id map.

I've tried using {for k, v in subscription_access_list_by_id : k => v } as an approach to no avail.

Comment: You have duplicate keys, and therefore you will need to restructure. Note there is no language that allows duplicate keys in maps, hashes, dictionaries, linked lists, etc., so there is no workaround here.

Answer (score 1):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

**`Variables.tf`**

```
variable "principal_ids" {

description = "The ID of the principal that is to be assigned the role at the given scope. Can be User, Group or SPN."
type = list(string)
default = ["cbd2d6bc-0d6e-4f13-bf7e-60207d82e674" ,"e396b90e-2309-490b-984f-7a8bab4eb625"]
}
```

**`Main.tf`**

```
locals {
principal_ids = toset(var.principal_ids)
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "custom" {
for_each = local.principal_ids
scope = data.azurerm_subscription.primary.id
role_definition_name = "Reader"
principal_id = each.key
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "contrib" {
for_each = local.principal_ids
scope = data.azurerm_subscription.primary.id
role_definition_name = "storage blob data reader"
principal_id = each.key
}
```

With above code I can add the role assignments like reader and storage-blob-data-reader to the service principal id.

**Console:**

[image]

**Portal:**
[image]

The role definition name should not be [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69577026/multiple-roles-in-a-resource-block-for-azurerm-role-assignment). If you need to add assign another user, you can create separate variable and assign to them.

**Reference:**
[azure - Create Role assignment dynamically in Terraform from input - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71197656/create-role-assignment-dynamically-in-terraform-from-input)